# Difference between running a python script locally vs in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, memory-management

I wrote a code to produce memory error but while I run it locally on my machine (i.e Mac OS) I am able to get memory error but while I run this code inside docker python container with limited ram assigned it doesn't throw any error. I don't know why. Sorry if you find this lame.

Here is the code:

```
def str_append(s):
    output = ''
    i = 0
    for i in range(100000000000000000):
        output += s
        i = i + 1
    print(sys.getsizeof(output))
    return output.encode('latin1')
print(str_append(string).decode('latin1'))
```

Docker file code

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY /test2.py .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "test2.py"]
```

First I build the image with `docker build -t mypytest .`

After that I run it with `docker run -m=23M -memory-swap=30M mypytest`

But it hangs without producing any output, when I check the stats:
[Docker Stats After Running The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VKuM.png)

Comment: please add the docker file and any other configuration you done.

Comment: what is `string` in the docker? I bet it's the empty string.

Comment: yes @AdamSmith I am not getting any output because it hangs right there after running it

Comment: @LinPy I've added the docker file and commands that I used to run

Comment: Your code as written crashes with a `NameError`.

Comment: `docker run` without interactive options actually "runs". It doesn't "hang", you are just running it in a way which does not interact. Try `docker run -it` (and probably `--rm` for good measure, otherwise you are leaving images around after they finish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works like this

script:

```
import sys
def str_append(s):
    output = ''
    i = 0
    for i in range(100000000000000000):
        output += s
        i = i + 1
        print(sys.getsizeof(output))
    return output.encode('latin1')
string = "hi"
str_append(string).decode('latin1')
```

after 2 min:

```
fc63c2658920        mypytest            "python test.py"         56 seconds ago      Exited (137) 9 seconds ago                       blissful_grothendieck
```

CPU and MEMORY were 100%

the size was `2609073726090737` when it killed

**PS**
set your identation for print in for to be able to see something (like in the code I added)

Comment: Did you limit your memory usage while running docker container? Can you please paste the docker run command here?

Comment: why did you add set those flags with -m and --memory-swap again ?

Comment: what do you mean ? I do not get you

Comment: Basically what is mypytestdocker and mypytest ? Just to confirm